# Call SuperConstructor from secondary constructor

Tags: kotlin, constructor, super

I have the class `Circle` which extends `CanvasElement`. 
I want to be able to create a circle just by giving a radius AND by initializing with the total set of values.
At the moment, my code looks clunky, setting each value from the super class one by one. How can I just call the super constructs with all values (posX, posY, etc. passed into the constructor call?

```
class Circle(var radius : Double = 0.0) : CanvasElement(){
constructor(posX : Double,
        posY : Double,
        radius : Double,
        fill : String,
        stroke : String) : this(radius){
    this.fill = fill
    this.stroke = stroke 

    this.posX = posX
    this.posY = posY
}
```

Class: CanvasElement

```
open class CanvasElement(
    var posX : Double = 0.0,
    var posY: Double = 0.0,
    var fill : String = "",
    var stroke : String = ""){
}
```

For a better understanding, I have added the java code for what I want to achieve:

**Circle**

```
public class Circle extends CanvasElement{
    private int radius;

    public Circle(int radius){
        super(0,0);
        this.radius = radius;
    }
}
```

**CanvasElement**

```
public class CanvasElement{
    private double posX;
    private double posY;

    public CanvasElement(double posX, double posY){
        this.posX = posX;
        this.posY = posY;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you would like to have something like this?

```
open class CanvasElement(var posX: Double , var posY: Double, var fill: String , var stroke: String)

class Circle(var radius: Double = 0.0,
             posX: Double = 0.0,
             posY: Double = 0.0,
             fill: String = "",
             stroke: String = "") : CanvasElement(posX, posY, fill, stroke)
```

IF I understood you properly you don't want `CanvasElement` to have deafults and you want to be able to create a `Circle` by defining only the `radius` and possibly other properties that `CanvasElement` has.

Comment: The problem with this is, that I need to have knowledge of the properties like posX etc in Circle. But I want them to be declared in the superclass. When I have multiple classes inheriting from CanvasElement I would need to adapt all these classes if CanvasElement gets a new property

Comment: Every property is declared in `CanvasElement` only radius is declared in `Circle`. My answer provides the exact code as your updated question (insted of the private modifier in the java code, but it is trivial to modify to have the properties be private).

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the defaults like you did in `CanvasElement`?:

```
class Circle(
    var radius : Double = 0.0,
    var posX : Double = 0.0,
    var posY: Double = 0.0,
    var fill : String = "",
    var stroke : String = ""
) : CanvasElement(posX, posY, fill, stroke)
```

This declaration will allow to pass any number of the parameters:

```
Circle() // Circle(radius = 0.0) + CanvasElement(0.0, 0.0, "", "")
Circle(10.0) // Circle(radius = 10.0) + CanvasElement(0.0, 0.0, "", "")
Circle(10.0, 1.0, 2.0, "red", "black") // Circle(radius = 10.0) + CanvasElement(1.0, 2.0, "red", "black")
```

Comment: But I want the properties (posX, posY,... ) declared in superclass CanvasElement and NOT in the subclass Circle

Comment: I edited the original example with java code, so that it might be clearer